# Calling Google Drive API using api key gives the error teamDriveMembershipRequired

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, api-key, google-drive-shared-drive

I have a test shared drive set up that has a few files in there. I was able to get a list of the files using files:list while using OAuth2.0 authentication. However I need to be able to do it using the api key. Calling files:list using the api key returns the message "The attempted action requires shared drive membership." I am reasonably certain the key is valid because I can call files:get on a file uploaded to my personal drive set to be viewable by anyone. I also tried setting a file in the shared drive to be publically visible, and it returns as "file not found".
Is there some sort of permissions setting on the shared drive itself that I should be aware of?

I am using Postman to do the calls, if that matters.

edit: My Postman request is:
[https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=drive&driveId=0ABlO2H7ti_OMUk9PVA&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&supportsTeamDrives=true&supportsAllDrives=true&key={{api_key}}](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=drive&driveId=0ABlO2H7ti_OMUk9PVA&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&supportsTeamDrives=true&supportsAllDrives=true&key=%7B%7Bapi_key%7D%7D)

Comment: Can you provide the code you've got so far?

Comment: I haven't got any code so far, I'm simply testing out the endpoints on Postman and seeing what they return.

Comment: Can you provide your postman erquest then?

Comment: Sure. I have edited the original question.

Comment: Are you running the request as yourself? Or as another user? What are the shared Drive settings? The user has to be a member of the shared drive, not just have public access to the file.